# Is there a documented meaning for the following Query syntax?

Tags: dataset, query

Consider this example:

```
a = <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>;

a // Query[Association["q" -> (# &)]]
(* <|"q" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>|> *)
```

It returns what I expect according to the documentation (see [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html), under Details):

[image]

Now consider the following:

```
a // Query[Association[("q" -> # &)]]
(* <|"q" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>|> *)
```

It returns the same thing. But what does it *actually* do? Is this documented syntax?

To phrase it another way: Should I treat this as valid usage or as undefined behaviour?

I typed something similar to this by accident. If I saw this code without the possibility to run it, I would say that it is nonsense and it should ideally trigger an error.

---

Here are the first two things that seemed reasonable to try:

```
Clear[fun1]
a // Query[Association[fun1]]
(* Association[(GeneralUtilities`SafeConstruct[#1, <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>] &)[Dataset`CompileSubquery[fun1]]] *)

fun2[val_] := "key" -> val
a // Query[Association[fun2]]
(* <|"key" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>|> *)
```

One triggers a bug (??) the other works just like my first example.

Comment: I probably fail to grasp the full the full extend of the problem, but I would interpret `a\\Query[Association[("q" -> # &)]]` as `Query[Association[Function[{x}, "q" -> x]]][a]` (this makes it easier for me to read). That form (as far as I can see) is documented as `Query[operator1,...][expr]` in the help section under details of `Query`. I would interpret `Function` as the operator here. Which would be indentical to your last definition (`fun2`).

Comment: Mhm sorry seems like I was mixing `Association[Function[...]]` with `Function[Association[...]]`. `Trace` output is also insanely long.

Comment: @Max1 Yes, what's written there is not a function, `f`, but a function wrapped in Association, `Association[f]`. Having `Association` here is important. Other heads don't behave this way. Also, while this thing has head `Association`, it is not an association (`AssociationQ`). It may become one after the contents are evaluated. If it does, it behaves just just the `<|"key" -> operator|>` form. If not, it returns some internal ugliness.

Comment: Yes I absolutely overlooked that. One thing which looked interesting to me is the very last part of the `Trace` of `Query[Association[Function[{x}, "q" -> x]]][a]`. One of the very last expressions is `(GeneralUtilities\`SafeConstruct[#1, <|"x" -> 1, "y" ->2|>] &) /@ Association[Dataset\`CompileSubquery[Function[{x}, "q" -> x]]]`. Since I'm not a mathematica wizard that looks like `#[<|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>] & /@ Association[Function[{x}, "q" -> x]]` to me with some internal mumbo jumbo. I realize tho that your main point is if this is documented or some kind of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Max1 Thanks for the phrasing, I included that in the question.

Comment: I think this is something that works accidentally.

Comment: Things are being mapped inside the general expression Association[function] (which is not an association), and then at the end we have Association[assoc] for some valid association assoc, which returns assoc.